# Update or refresh datatable

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-cloud-firestore, datatables

How can someone update or refresh a datatable which does not use Ajax or JSON as its data source. In my case I am using data from Firestore. I would like my datatable to refresh or update once I delete a document.

Answer (score 0):

Use can use `location.reload();` to refresh

Comment: I wouldn't want to use location.reload(). I want the datatable to appear as realtime

Comment: Then you have to use ajax. Ajax is mainly for async purpose only, without reloading the whole it reloads the required content of the page